# Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, browser, android-studio

I have a project developed in Eclipse. Now I have to make some changes in it and I am not using Eclipse now.
But after creating the same project in Android Studio I am not able to use

- `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`
- `Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK`
- `Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS`
- `Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());`

**UPDATE**

It shows following errors:

- Cannot resolve: "BOOKMARKS_URI"
- Cannot resolve: "BookmarkColumns"
- Cannot resolve: "clearHistory()"

Please help me...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you be more specific about "not being able to use"? What happens if you try these things, do you get an error message? Please edit that into your post. With more information we may be able to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this instead of accessing directly from browser Because Once i had the same issue and solved it by this hope it will help you

```
public final Uri BOOKMARKS_URI = Uri.parse("content://browser/bookmarks");
public final String[] HISTORY_PROJECTION = new String[]{
            "_id", // 0
            "url", // 1
            "visits", // 2
            "date", // 3
            "bookmark", // 4
            "title", // 5
            "favicon", // 6
            "thumbnail", // 7
            "touch_icon", // 8
            "user_entered", // 9
    };
public final int HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX = 5;
public final int HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this alternative way for those who still didn't found a way to get browser history:

public static final Uri BOOKMARKS_URI = Uri.parse("content://browser/bookmarks");

Comment: i will surely give it a try upon getting time